# Open custom URI which is registered in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, uri, windows-8.1

i like to "open" a (local) customized URI witch is already registered in Windows 8.1.
I can open it, if the Link is embedded in a HTML Mail.

```html
<a href="cobra://goto/addresses/ID=5545">
```

and it works in Windows Explorer:

cobra://goto/addresses/ID=5545

The ID is sent to the Cobra Application.

I tried to send this URI to the Cobra Application with a WebRequest / FileWebRequest / HttpWebRequest without any Success.

```c#
string uriToLaunch = @"cobra://goto/addresses/ID=" + ID;
Uri uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
FileWebRequest WebReq = (FileWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
WebReq.GetResponse();
```

Error: System.NotSupportedException: "URI prefix is not recognized."

Second try, after I recognized that the URI work with Windows Explorer:

```c#
File.Open(uriToLaunch, FileMode.Open);
```

Error: System.NotSupportedException: "The given path's format is not supported."

Any Suggestions how to do it? I don´t want to build my own URI Parser because Windows knows how to handle it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run a custom URI from C# by calling `Process.Start()`

eg

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("uri://here");
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is occurring because your uri string is not formatted correctly (you have two prefixes - url: and cobra:)

Try the following:

```
string uriToLaunch = @"cobra://goto/addresses/ID=" + ID;
```

Comment: Was another try with "URL:cobra:..." but was not the Problem.

Comment: Sorry for my bad answer, your are right too. But the main Problem solved with the answer from tocsoft. ;-)